# Sails.js Increment Attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js, and trying to increment an attribute in my model by one when a function is called. It works and increments and return JSON with the value as 1, but never saves to the database, so when I make a get request later, the value is still 0.

Function:

```
addVote: function (req, res, next) {

    Nomination.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundNomination(err, nom) {
      if(err) return next(err);

      if(!nom) return next();

      Nomination.update(req.param('id'), {
        votes: nom.votes++
      })

      return res.json({
        votes : nom.votes
      });

    });
},
```

EDIT:

Now this is weird. Must be some scoping issue. When I change the code to this, the console outputs 0 then 1. If I take out the second console.log, it outputs 1...

```
addVote: function (req, res, next) {
    var newVotes = 0;

    Nomination.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundNomination(err, nom) {
      if(err) return next(err);
      if(!nom) return next();

      nom.votes++;
      newVotes = nom.votes;
      console.log(newVotes);
    });

    console.log(newVotes);

    Nomination.update(req.param('id'), {
        votes: newVotes
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

        return res.json({
            votes : newVotes
        });
    });

},
```

AHHA! It's calling the Update function before findOne. But why, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do this :

```
nom.votes++; //or nom.votes = nom.votes+1;
Nomination.update(req.param('id'), 
      {
        votes: nom.votes
      }).exec(function(err, itemUpdated)
      {
         if(err)//error
         {
           //manage error 
         }
         else
         {
            res.json({
              votes : itemUpdated.votes
            });
         }
      });
```

All database access are asynchronous so you have to call `exec` method for `create` `update` ect.. on a model

In the end you have :

```
addVote: function (req, res, next) {
    var newVotes = 0;

    Nomination.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundNomination(err, nom)
{
    if (err)
    {
        return next(err);
    }

    nom.votes++;
    newVotes = nom.votes;
    console.log(newVotes);
    Nomination.update(req.param('id'), {
        votes : newVotes
    }, function (err)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            return res.negotiate(err);
        }

        return res.json({
            votes : newVotes
        });
    });
});
},
```

Comment: It increments votes, it just never saves it to the model. In fact, that prevents it from incrementing at all.

Comment: Nope, that's still not working. It returns votes: 1 in the JSON, but when I make a get request, votes: 0

Comment: See my last edit for your other problem, you have to think asynchronous :) findOne et Update are both asynchronous so make first find and then update

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late to the party but I might have an simpler fix. When you put ++ after a number it adds one to the value but it returns the value before doing this. If you want the value of nom.votes after it has been incremented by one all you need to do is put the ++ before the value, then it will return the value after adding one, like this:

```
return res.json({
    votes : ++nom.votes
});
```